# Duvida sobre codigo no C#/ Unity

Tags: c#, unity2d

Olá! Estou com uma dúvida sobre um código no C#.
Eu fiz um script na Unity com um contador de IEnumetor e Coroutine  e coloquei uma condição: ele roda junto com um cronômetro e ele reseta quando o cronômetro chega em 8 minutos.

Em outro Script eu tenho uma variável que recebe esse contador, porem eu gostaria que esse script fosse somando os valores do contador sem resetar. Por exemplo:

No primeiro script vamos supor que quando da 8 min, ele reseta o cronômetro e o contador está em 100, ai ele reseta também e começa denovo 0,1,2,3...

No segundo script eu gostaria de salvar esse valor "100" e ir adicionando os valores do contador sem resetar(101,102,103...)
Não consegui achar nada a respeito e
Devido a minha falta de conhecimento em programação eu nao sei como fazer isso ou se e  possivel.
Se alguem puder ajudar agradeço.

esse é  o código do contador:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class teste : MonoBehaviour
{

    [SerializeField] TMP_Text ContadorText;


    public static double Cont;
    public Button Botao;




    void Start()
    {

        // botao de iniciar o contador
        Botao.onClick.AddListener(() => Ligar());

    }


    private void Update()
    {
        StartCoroutine(Cronometro(1));

    }

    public void Ligar()

    {
        StartCoroutine(Contador(1000));

    }


    public void Desligar()
    {

        StopAllCoroutines();

     }



    IEnumerator Contador(int max)
    {
        
        var C = 0;
        while (C <= 1000)
        {
            ContadorText.SetText(C.ToString());
            yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(1);
            C += 1;
            Cont = c;
           
        }
    }



    IEnumerator Cronometro(int max)
    {
       
        if (Calendario.Minuto >= 8)
        {

            yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(1);
            Desligar();
            Ligar();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: No segundo script eu uso a variável "public static double Cont" para receber  o valor do contador.

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score -2):

Quando você roda a coroutine você está sobrepondo o valor que deveria ser salvo na variavel "Cont", no caso você deveria acrescentar o valor durante a execução da coroutine.

Seu código está fazendo o seguinte:

1seg => C recebe 0+1, C = 1 e poe o valor de C em Cont

2seg => C recebe 1+1, C = 2 e poe o valor de C em Cont

A próxima coroutine quando iniciar vai tá sobrepondo os mesmos valores, tenta usando o operador de Adição
Cont += C no final da coroutine

Exemplo:

```
public static double Cont = 0;

[...]
IEnumerator Contador(int max)
{
    var C = 0;
    while (C <= 1000)
    {
        ContadorText.SetText(C.ToString());
        yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(1);
        C += 1;
       
    }
    Cont += C;
}
[...]
```

Nesse código ele adiciona de 1000 em 1000, caso queira de 1 em 1 é só tentar por no laço.

```
public static double Cont = 0;

[...]
IEnumerator Contador(int max)
{
    var C = 0;
    while (C <= 1000)
    {
        ContadorText.SetText(C.ToString());
        yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(1);
        C += 1;
        Cont += 1;
    }
}
[...]
```

Acredito que isso pode funcionar pro que você quer

Comment: Funcionou exatamente como eu precisava. Muito obrigado Lucao.